# Google Plus Share Button not always showing image

Tags: php, html

I'm using the Google plus Share API. On the following page when I click the G+ share button, in the corresponding captcha screen i'm not seeing the attached og:image. On other pages with equal code I do. For example http://www.partypakjes.nl/dames/zwarte-petticoat-halflang works just fine. Can anyone please provide pointers how to get the image to show? Much appreciated!

Page: http://www.partypakjes.nl/blog/ouwe-sunder-2015
Code:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Party Pakjes | Extra openingstijden Ouwe Sunder 2015" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.partypakjes.nl/blog/ouwe-sunder-2015" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http:/www.partypakjes.nl/images/blogimages/big/Ouwe%20Sunder.jpg" />

<a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.partypakjes.nl/blog/ouwe-sunder-2015" class="social-media-google js-social-popup">
<div class="icon-google-plus"></div>
<div class="google-count">0</div>
</a>
```

Thanks for the help.
Floris﻿

Comment: The only difference from the two example pages is that you are using **space** on your image file name. Try rename the image without space.

Comment: Thanks! The space was not the problem, it was the one slash after http: in the og:image section. I do now see an image, but it's not the correct one. It's another one on that page. I'll try without the space and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

from **Google** documentation:

- **Why isn't my +Snippet image appearing?**
  Images that are too small or not square enough are not included in the +Snippet, even if the images are explicitly referenced by schema.org microdata or Open Graph markup. Specifically, the height must be at least 120px, and if the width is less than 100px, then the aspect ratio must be no greater than 3.0
- *Note: The logic that fetches the +Snippet data respects cache-control directives, so changes to your page might not immediately be reflected in the +Snippet.*